# Doubt in Linear SVM solving with mathematical equations

Tags: mathematical-statistics, linear-model, svm

I am following the paper https://axon.cs.byu.edu/Dan/678/miscellaneous/SVM.example.pdf and trying to solve the SVM on paper using mathematical equations.
When I try to solve them, I get different set of w and b..

My doubt is : how do I know the w and b that I get from equation is optimal one?
α1Φ(s1) · Φ(s1) + α2Φ(s2) · Φ(s1) + α3Φ(s3) · Φ(s1) = +1

α1Φ(s1) · Φ(s2) + α2Φ(s2) · Φ(s2) + α3Φ(s3) · Φ(s2) = +1

α1Φ(s1) · Φ(s3) + α2Φ(s2) · Φ(s3) + α3Φ(s3) · Φ(s3) = -1

s1~ = (3, 1 , 1)

s2~ = (3, −1, 1)

s3~ = (1, 0, 1)

Please note: the difference in output arises as I have considered 3 points in different order.

11α1 + 9α2 + 4α3 = +1

9α1 + 9α2 + 4α3 = +1

4α1 + 4α2 + 2α3 = -1

w = (5.5 ,3)
b = 3.5

Could you help me clear my understanding? Is my solution still a valid solution for hyperplane by SVM?

BR,
J

Comment: @Xavier Bourret Sicotte 
could you please help